# How to identify which adaptive card the inputs from the user are related to?

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am learning the Bot Framework V4 version and I have implemented a simple example. I would ask the user to enter two numbers via an adaptive card and once he clicks on the submit operation, I would just add them and send a response back to the user, the computed sum. Now I wanted to extend this further. I also want to add a multiplication option too. I am attaching the code below for your reference:

```
// ++PDIT: Documentation can be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/turncontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#activity
// ++PDIT: Adaptive Cards Schema: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/

const restify = require('restify');
const botbuilder = require('botbuilder');

// ++PDIT: Add the reference to the AdaptorCards' JSON here.
const InputNumbersCard = require('./resources/InputNumbers.json');

// Create bot adapter, which defines how the bot sends and receives messages.
// ++PDIT: If the adapter is fed with an empty appId and appPassword, then the
// processActivity would be treated as a conversation/dialog via an Emulator. 
var adapter = new botbuilder.BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Create HTTP server.
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log(`\n${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
});

// Listen for incoming requests at /api/messages.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Use the adapter to process the incoming web request into a TurnContext object.
    // ++PDIT: TurnContext object represents the bot's 'turn', in a conversation flow.
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // Do something with this incoming activity!

        if ( turnContext.activity.type === 'message' ) {
            // ++PDIT: Get the user's utterance here
            const utterance = turnContext.activity.text;

            // ++PDIT: 'postBack' - Upon submitting an activity dialog, the information
            // stored by the user actually gets stored on the adaptive card itself.
            if( turnContext.activity.channelData.postBack ) {
              // AdaptiveCard submit operation.
              var number1 = turnContext.activity.value.firstNumber;
              var number2 = turnContext.activity.value.secondNumber;

              var sum = Number(number1) + Number(number2);
              await turnContext.sendActivity( 'The sum of the entered numbers is ' + sum );
            }
            else {
              if ( utterance === 'add' || utterance === 'multiply' ) {
                  // send a reply
                  await turnContext.sendActivity( {
                    text: `Here is an Adaptive Card for entering the two number that you want to ${utterance}:`,
                    attachments:[botbuilder.CardFactory.adaptiveCard(InputNumbersCard)] 
                  });
              }
              else {
                  // send a reply
                  await turnContext.sendActivity(`I heard you say '${ utterance }'. I am yet to learn that skill!.`);
              }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My adaptive card looks like below:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Enter the numbers that you would like to add"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "firstNumber",
        "placeholder": "What is your first number?"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "secondNumber",
        "placeholder": "What is your second number?"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Action"        
      }
    ]
}
```

I have read that when the user clicks on the submit button, the variable turnContext.activity.channelData.postBack would be true. But my question is this: How would I understand that the inputs that the user has entered are actually for 'add' operation or for 'multiple' operation?. I am using a single adaptive card as you can see as I felt add and multiply are just generic in the sense they need two constants to work with. So I am a bit lost here. Request you to point me to the right direction.

Thanks
Pavan.

Comment: You should probably add another field to your card, like a dropdown for example where the user can choose between add or multiply or subtract or whatever you want to add. The submited data will then give you whatever the user picked and you can go from there

Comment: I understand what you are pointing to. But in my case, I am already asking the user what he wants to do upfront. Once he picks up the operation type, I am actually showing the adaptive card. So wanted to know how this can be handled.